# ggplot the coef with 95%CI, by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I would like to use ggplot to plot my result of the association of air pollutant with birth weight changes (95%CI).

the format of my data is like this

```
variable    exposure period      coef    coef_lb      coef_ub
PM10        entire pregnancy    -27.6      -49.2         -3.8
SO2         entire pregnancy       40       14.2         62.8
NO          entire pregnancy      -26        -44         -6.4
NO2         entire pregnancy        0        -20           19
PM10        trimester1          -29.4      -49.4           -8
SO2         trimester1             12         -9         31.8
NO          trimester1            5.2      -15.2         28.2
NO2         trimester1           -2.2        -23         16.6
PM10        trimester2          -11.8      -35.2         11.2
SO2         trimester2           26.2          2         51.4
NO          trimester2          -10.8      -35.2         12.4
NO2         trimester2           -7.4      -27.8         14.6
PM10        trimester3            6.2      -17.6         28.2
SO2         trimester3            0.6        -19         22.4
NO          trimester3            -24        -43         -5.4
NO2         trimester3              7      -11.4         26.8
```

I have four types of air pollutants, exposure period is trimester-specific, and I have the coef, and the lower bound and upper bound of 95%CI.

I want to plot a graph like the one below, can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `?geom_errorbar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#get the data.frame
data <- read.table("DATA.csv",header=T,sep=";")

require(ggplot2)

#build and plot ggplot object
g <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=exposureperiod,y=coef))
g <- g + facet_grid(.~variable)
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=coef_lb,ymax=coef_ub))
g
```

[image]

Comment: Hi CMichael, can you also help me add the Rscript for 1) changing the scale of y-axis; 2) changing the subgroup label of x-axis; 3) adding the point of coef on the line; 4) get rid of the short lines at the two ends, or make them shorter; 5) changing the x-axis title (i.e. exposureperiod) Thank you very much!

Comment: 1) g <- g + ylim(lower,upper)
2) Easiest would be changing the names in your data?
3) g <- g + geom_point()
4) use geom_pointrange instead of geom_errorbar
5) g <- g + xlab("new label")

Comment: That solves my problems. Thank you! Sorry I got another two problems here. 1) is it possible to switch the sequence of the graphs as well? I mean, I want to display "PM10", "SO2", "NO" & "NO2" from left to right. 2) how could I change the "10" in "PM10" into subscript ?

Comment: For the first you should google / search on SO "reorder factor ggplot", there are many answers. The second one is less obvious to me but again try googling "subscript facet label" ggplot and if that does not help put a well posed question up here referring to this question.